# how to display telugu font in pdf in java

Tags: java, pdf, fonts, itext

while i am trying to add in pdf reading from text document phrase like వ్యవసాయ శాఖ, శాఖాధిపతి
it displaying like

[image: output text]

my code is like

```
  Document document = new Document();
  PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileForPdf);

  document.open();

  Paragraph  paragraph=      new Paragraph();
  BaseFont bf_cjk = BaseFont.createFont("F:\\Downloads\\gautami.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
  Font cjk = new Font(bf_cjk, 8,Font.NORMAL);
  paragraph.setFont(cjk);
  paragraph.add(వ్యవసాయ శాఖ, శాఖాధిపతి");
  document.add(paragraph);

  document.close();
  fileForPdf.close();
```

please help me ,i am new to this .

Comment: It seems a problem of enabling font ligature?

Comment: Do have a look here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11366354/itext-whats-going-on-with-font-basefont-and-createfont] once!

Comment: may be, i dont know how to do it

Comment: The old itext versions (before 7.x) used to not handle ligatures. For proper literature support switch to itext 7 and add the typography module.

Comment: can you tell how to do it?

Comment: @mkl your are right , just added maven itext typography dependency module and its working fine,Thank you:)

Comment: You do know that the typography module is the pdfCalligraph add-on, which is a closed source module and you must buy a license to use it.

Comment: yeah i just came to know after reading their docs ,I am currently on free trail for 30 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Geno Chen correctly remarked in his comment, this is a matter of ligature usage. Before version 7 itext did not built ligatures from character groups. Thus, in case of the OP's original code for itext 5, the characters were displayed incorrectly.

Itext version 7 does build ligatures from character groups if the typography module pdfCalligraph is used.

Thus, the way to go is updating to itext 7 and the pdfCalligraph add-on. As the OP already confirmed, this works as desired:

> just added maven itext typography dependency module and its working fine

---

As Amedee Van Gasse correctly remarked, pdfCalligraph

> is a closed source module and you must buy a license to use it.

You can test it for some weeks using a test license.

Comment: is there any opensource library available for this problem?

Comment: You might try to use ICU for pre-processing your text and then using this pre-processed as input of pdf library text showing commands. I haven't tried that, so I cannot tell whether that's a good approach.